# Screen flicker/freeze when attaching NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

In my application I have some screens where I have map loaded. I am overriding the NFC selection dialog (when you attach the NFC tag a selection dialog appears or is any application listens for NFC events it launches automatically). No selection dialog is shown, nor any application is launched when I attach the NFC tag but the screen flickers/freezes for 1 second or less. This happens only in the screens where I have a map loaded. Other screens are not reacting like this. What can be the problem? Can I somehow make the map screens work like the others ?

This is some base activity which other activities extend in order to override

```
public class NavigatorBaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

private String[][] mTechLists;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // initiate NFC in order to catch onNewIntent
    if (NaviApp.checkMinApiLevel10()) {
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() } };
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass())
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("NavigatorBaseFragmentActivity", "Detected NFC tag attach");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // listen for NFC tag attachment
    if (NaviApp.checkMinApiLevel10()) {
        if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
            mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent,
                    null, mTechLists);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My NavigationActivity where the map is displayed extends this base activity.

Comment: What exactly do you need ? To know what to post

Comment: the codes of *overriding the NFC selection dialog*, probably making the screen flicker / freeze